# Accepting a JSON data in TypeScript in showing it in a table form

Tags: json, typescript, angular2-routing

I am new to typescript,

I want to accept a JSON data whose size is no fix...

After accepting a data i want it to show in table form...

My JSON data will be like

> [{"regionID":1 "regionname":"Can"},
>
> {"regionID":1 "regionname":"Cen"}]

and the field if that table is not editable...

Comment: do you think is it a valid question? useless one.before you post make sure you read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If not why would i ask that...?

Comment: where is the code? then? what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Well, the typescript way to do it would be to create a class, let's call it region:

```
Class Region {
  regionId: number;
  regionName: string;

  constructor(id, name) {
    regionId = id;
    regionName = name;
  }
}
```

then you should convert the result JSON into array of that class.

```
regions: Region[] = new Array<Region>();

JSON.parse(myJson).forEach(item => {
    regions.push(new Region(item));
});
```

Showing it in a table should be very similar to how you work in javascript, typescript should not be an issue for that matter (you might want to describe it in a different question, as it seems of topic)